# Accessing internal libcurl ptrs

Tags: php, c++, static, libcurl

I'm currently using `libcurl` to check a `php` script and write its output to a file.  I want to add in error messages, and to do so I was planning on reading the data before it is written to the file, check for `php`'s error messages, and if they exist cancel the file writing and return the error message.  My code is:

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) 
{ 
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int PhpQuerier::getBlob(string* frameName, string fn)
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    string query = "http://192.168.1.14/selectBlob.php?tableNameFAIL=frame_info&bColName=frame_data&selectCon=frame_name='";
    query.append(*frameName); query.append("'");        

    const char *url = query.c_str();
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(fn.c_str(),"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        fclose(fp);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I added in the `FAIL` to `tableName` to make sure my code would fail.

What I need to do is access the `void *ptr` in write_data.  If I add `printf("%*.*s",size * nmemb, size * nmemb, ptr);` I can print the value, but I need to access that in the main function, not just the static write_data.

Can I access ptr in getBlob? Or failing that, is it possible to create a global variable that can see both static write_data and getBlob?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The callback gets all data, you can easily append all data to a single buffer in memory and check that for the strings you're looking for - and keep writing to the file. If that's truly want you want.

A fine and easy example showing how to receive the entire response into a memory buffer can be found here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html